# Can't load Assembly System.Net.Http.Formatting in .Net Solution

Tags: .net, nuget, package, .net-assembly

I get the following error when trying to update-package on the NuGet Console:

```
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Update-Package], 
InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :     
NuGetMissingPackages, 
NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

When I try to install `NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets` I get the error:

```
An error occured while trying to restore packages:Unable to find version '5.2.3' of package 'System.Net.Http.Formatting'.
```

In the .csproj file  the version is 5.2.3 for System.Net.Http.Formatting

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension.5.2.3.0\lib\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

...and in the `packages.config` file the version is 5.2.3 for the package `System.Net.Http.Formatting`:

```
<package id="System.Net.Http.Formatting" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461"/>
```

In the properties of references the version is 4.1.1.2 and the runtime version is v4.0.30319 for `System.Net.Http.Formatting`.

So my problem is that I cannot reinstall `System.Net.Http.Formatting` because it is now part of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` apparently and when I try to install it I get the original error. I am going around in circles.
If I just run the project as it is it compiles and I get the runtime error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.6.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly 
reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
```

Where is it getting this version 5.2.6.0 from? And if it is a dependency that is the problem I need to reinstall but I can't.

I am very inexperienced with packages and NuGet. All these problems arose when a coworker updated a few packages and put these changes in git but my project did not compile.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem. I deleted the DLL `System.Net.Http.Formatting`. I made sure it was deleted from the `.csproj` file and the `packages.config` file.

Then I uninstalled the packages `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost`, `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` and `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` using NuGet.

Then I reinstalled the packages using NuGet, but I did not reinstall the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` package.

The dependent code in that originally required it is now in part of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`. It installed the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` package and the version 5.2.6 which my Solution was originally looking for and complaining about when it could not find it.

Answer (score 8):

I just need to update my `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` within the NuGet to latest version 5.2.7 and the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` gets updated too.

Clean your project and rebuild.

Comment: Today, you are my hero. Thank you, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the latest version of NuGet package  **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client** and then uninstalled *System.Net.Http.Formatting*. After uninstalling package *System.Net.Http.Formatting*, then only the warning message went away.